# Labeling Multi-Dimensional Array Coordinates in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing, grid

What I would like to do is label the coordinante(grid[0][0]) as 'A1', (grid[0][1]) as 'A2', (grid[1][0]) as 'B1' , (grid[1][1]) as 'B2' and so on. I am creating a game where the player must select the coordinates in order to remove the content of it before the game starts.

> ```
>   B W B W                                  A1 A2 A3 A4
>   W B W B    I want to access like this    B1 B2 B3 B4
>   B W B W                                  C1 C2 C3 C4
> ```

As of right now, I am asking the user which piece('B' or 'W') that they would like to remove(can be any of their own pieces). I would like them to be able to type 'A1' for the top left 'B'.

> ```
> removeB = input("BLACK, remove one of your pieces by typing in it's coordinates")
> ```

I'm not sure how to go about assigning the A1,A2,B1,B2 'variables' to the designated coordinates. I would like to be able to do something like:

> ```
> if(removeB == A1):
>       grid[row -1][col -1].append('-')       # '-' = empty
> ```

If it helps, I have attached my code below:

> ```
>  import random
>   numrows = 3
>   numcols = 4
>   def initial():
>      grid = []
>      count = 0
>      y = 2
>      for x in range(numrows)s
>      grid.append([])
>      for y in range(numcols):
>         if ((x + y)%2):    
>             grid[x].append('W')  
>         else:
>             grid[x].append('B')  
>   for x in grid:       
>     print(*x, sep=' ',end="\n")
>   print("")
>   color = input("Press 'Enter' to see which color you will be playing")
>   print("")
>   rand=random.randrange(1,3)
>   if(rand == 1):
>       print("Player1 you will be playing as BLACK")
>       print("Player2 you will be playing as WHITE")
>   else:
>       print("Player1 you will be playing as WHITE")
>       print("Player2 you will be playing as BLACK")
>  print("")
>  print(" The game board can be navigated as if it were: ")
>  print("")
>  example = '''\
>  A1 A2 A3 A4        B W B W    
>  B1 B2 B3 B4   =    W B W B
>  C1 C2 C3 C4        B W B W
>  '''
>  print(example)
>  print("and so on.....")
>  print("")
>  if(rand == 1):
>       removeB = input("~BLACK Player, remove one of your pieces by typing in the coordinates: ")
>       removeW = input("~WHITE Player, remove one of your pieces by typing in the coordinates: ")
>   else:
>       removeW = input("~WHITE Player, remove one of your pieces by typing in the coordinates: ")
>       removeB = input("~BLACK Player, remove one of your pieces by typing in the coordinates: ")
> ```

Thank you in advance for the time and effort taken to answer my questions.

P.S. I know that my code is very nooby. I'm only 3 weeks into python lol. I am not done with the code, just hung up on this part....

Answer (score 0):

As far as labeling the grid coordinates, I found that I could just use the variable 'removeB'(stored user input) inside of an if statement. So if    (removeB == "1") then set the coordinates of grid[0][0] from 'B' to '-' (empty)

> ```
> newgrid = copy_grid(board) # here is where i copied the board (with separate function)
> if(removeB == "1"): #if BLACKS's input is 1
>     newgrid[0][0] = '-' #Change the top left grid coordinate value (grid[0][0]) to '-'
> elif(removeB == "3"): #because coordinate 2 is a W piece, I skip to 3 likewise as we go
>     newgrid[0][2] = '-'
> elif(removeB == "6"):
>     newgrid[1][1] = '-'
> elif(removeB == "8"):
>     newgrid[1][3] = '-'
> elif(removeB == "9"):
>     newgrid[2][0] = '-'#changes bottom left B to -
> elif(removeB == "11"):
>     newgrid[2][2] = '-'
> if(removeW == "2"): #start comparing WHITE's input
>     newgrid[0][1] = '-'
> elif(removeW == "4"):
>     newgrid[0][3] = '-'#changes top right W to -
> elif(removeW == "5"):
>     newgrid[1][0] = '-'
> elif(removeW == "7"):
>     newgrid[1][2] = '-'
> elif(removeW == "10"):
>     newgrid[2][1] = '-'
> elif(removeW == "12"):
>     newgrid[2][3] = '-'#changes bottom right W to -
> board = copy_grid(newgrid)#copy the newgrid, which contains altered coordinates
> show_grid(board)#function that prints out the new board with altered coordinates
> ```

This is my reslut:

```
 B W B W   <-gameboard             1  2  3  4
 W B W B                           5  6  7  8
 B W B W           coordinates->   9 10 11 12

BLACK's user input = 1
WHITE's user input = 12
```

Output:

```
 - W B W  
 W B W B   
 B W B -
```

I did not include a couple of the functions that I used in above, however their actions do just as they are named. If you have any questions pertaining to whatever I covered here, I would be glad to share other aspects of my findings.